# Changing background colour of wx.MDIParentFrame

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

The default colour of the background of a wx.MDIParentFrame is a dark gray colour. I would like to change that colour.

Does anyone know how?

http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.MDIParentFrame-class.html
I cant see a way to change the default background, Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since it inherits from Frame cant you just do

```
my_MIDIParentFrame.SetBackgroundColour("black") ?
```

maybe instead you could do

```
wx.Frame.SetBackgroundColour(my_MIDI_PARENT_FRAME,"black")
```

I dont know for sure ... but I think those will work...

Comment: Thanks for the reply but nothing happens when I try this. I am running on XP

Comment: hmmm dang I thought that would work... anyway  here is an example where colors are set http://opensourcejavaphp.net/python/wxpython/wxPython/demo/MDISashDemo.py.html   but its not quite what you want but may help

Comment: That is a good example but I cant get it to work here, its a little problematic. Do you think this could be done using a panel then setting the color of the panel?

Comment: My experience using any `SetBackgroundColour()` method is that you need to call `Refresh()` on the object afterwards before it will change the colour. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with MDIAUIParentFrame

http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/15083/10202/